# install XAMPP from network drive

Tags: xampp

Is it possible to run XAMPP from network drive? And is it possible to have multiple users for XAMPP that has been installed to network harddisk? . If yes, how can I go about configuring it to work?
when I try to install it on the drive I get this:

> the installation directory must be a path containing only letters,
>   numbers and the characters ‘/‘,’.’ and ‘_’.

the path I'm using is : \SERVEUR-NAS\Laboratoire\xampp

Any info is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: \\SERVEUR-NAS\Laboratoire\xampp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the directory path on the network drive from SERVEUR-NAS\Laboratoire\xampp to SERVEUR_NAS\Laboratoire\xampp?
Replacing '-' with '_' in 'SERVEUR-NAS, might be all that's needed according to the error shown.